# Career options after Ph.D. Data Science in academia

Tags: phd, postdocs, data-science

What are the different options available to earn one's living, after completing PhD in Data Science, at the age of 50 or 55?

I have completed my Masters in my early 40s and got a job from campus. My grades are good. I am thinking of continuing with the job for a few years, and then try for Ph.D..

I do not care if my classmates call me aunty or grandma. Surprises do not stay for long, rather it feels good to be a good example for others. Also, I have seen some colleagues doing part time Ph.D., but I am not interested in that as I don't think I can give my 100% in two things together. I am looking for a full time course, from a good institute.

I am concerned about -

1. Whether I will like doing Ph.D. as it takes years. (I liked my masters, though it was stressful, because I learnt a lot of things there. I heard some people saying Ph.D. is very frustrating, so I am asking this.)
2. After completing Ph. D., what is next? What are the different opportunities possible for earning? Will age matter?

Comment: For 2, are you asking about jobs in academia (as the title indicates)?  If so, it doesn't matter that your PhD is in data science, the options are as in all of STEM: postdoc, or teaching, or research position (plus a few less common options).  As far as age bias, this will depend on both the position and the places your looking for jobs at.